# Dudas con el control remoto en la barra de notificaciones de Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

Buenas, primero quiero hacer un breve resumen para poner en situación.
Mi app carga un `Fragment`, en él instancio un objeto a partir de una `clase` que he creado. Esta `clase` contiene los atributos y métodos necesarios para reproducir una radio en Streaming.
En el `Fragment` hago las llamadas a los métodos del `objeto` y funciona correctamente.

También en el `Fragment` instancio una `clase` llamada `NotificationPanel`, a la cual le paso el `objeto` de la radio. Esta `clase` tiene todo lo necesario o eso creo, para poder visualizar en la barra de notificaciones un `layout` con los botones del control remoto de la radio en Streaming.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public class NotificationPanel {

private Context parent;
private NotificationManager nManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
private RemoteViews remoteView;
private RadioOnline radio;

public NotificationPanel(Context parent, RadioOnline radio) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.parent = parent;
    this.radio = radio;
    nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(parent)
            .setContentTitle("Mi Radio")
            .setContentText("Radio Online activada")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setOngoing(true);

    remoteView = new RemoteViews(parent.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);

    //set the button listeners
    setListeners(remoteView);
    nBuilder.setContent(remoteView);

    nManager = (NotificationManager) parent.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(2, nBuilder.build());
}

public void setListeners(RemoteViews view){
    //listener icono
    Intent icon = new Intent(parent, NotificationReturnSlot.class);
    icon.putExtra("DO", "icon");
    PendingIntent btnIcon = PendingIntent.getActivity(parent, 0, icon, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButtonNbarLogo, btnIcon);
    //listener 1
    Intent play = new Intent(parent, NotificationReturnSlot.class);
    play.putExtra("DO", "play");
    PendingIntent btnPlay = PendingIntent.getActivity(parent, 0, play, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlayNbar, btnPlay);

    //listener 2
    Intent stop = new Intent(parent, NotificationReturnSlot.class);
    stop.putExtra("DO", "stop");
    //stop.putExtra("DO2", radio);
    PendingIntent btnStop = PendingIntent.getActivity(parent, 1, stop, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnStopNbar, btnStop);
}


/**
 * Método que cierra el NotificationBar
 */
public void notificationCancel() {
    nManager.cancel(2);
}
}
```

Cómo se puede apreciar, en el `método` setListener, se crean un `Intent` por cada botón que hay en el `layout`. Estos `Intent` se le pasan a la `clase` NotificationResultSlot. La cual analiza que Intent ha sido recibido y ejecuta una acción.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public class NotificationReturnSlot extends Activity {

private NotificationReturnSlot ctx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ctx = this;
    String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("DO");
    if (action.equals("play")) {
        Log.i("NotificationReturnSlot", "play");
    } else if (action.equals("stop")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Botón stop pulsado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("NotificationReturnSlot", "stopNotification");
    }
    finish();
}
}
```

Los dos problemas que tengo son los siguientes:

Primero, no se si esto funciona, ya que tengo un `Toast` en la acción del botón Stop, y no se muestra cuando lo pulso.

Lo segundo, es que no veo la manera de de pasar el objeto radio, por el Intent, ya que si se lo paso `stop.putExtra("DO2", radio);` Me dice que tengo que hacer un `Cast` a `Parceable` o a `Seralizable`, pues cuando lo hago y lo ejecuto con cualquiera de los dos `Cast`, me dice que el objeto no puede ser convertido.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar esto? ¿Puede ser que esté planteando mal la forma de programar para android?

Espero haber sido conciso y haberme explicado bien de cual es el problema.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Los intents se utilizan para pasar información entre activitys y fragments, no para pasar objetos como "RadioOnline radio", si quieres enviar info de ese objeto, obten cada información y envíalo

Comment: Ok intentaré hacer lo que dices, muchas gracias por la aclaración de los Intents

Comment: Al final decidí cambiar el método con el que trabajar con los botones.
En el siguiente enlace, he expuesto cómo lo hice: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33872/duda-con-el-broadcastreceiver-no-registra-las-acciones/34127#34127 Un saludo y muchas gracias.