# Duda con el BroadCastreceiver, no registra las acciones

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Tengo creada una `clase`, la cual extiende de `BroadcastReceiver`. Esta clase la uso para mostrar una barra de notificaciones con dos botones para poder registrar cada clic.

La barra de notificaciones se muestra perfectamente, pero cuando hago clic en los botones, no hace absolutamente nada.

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo registrar en la misma clase el clic de cada botón.

El código de mi clase es el siguiente:

```
public class NotificationPanel extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context parent;
private NotificationManager nManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
private RemoteViews remoteView;
private RadioOnline radio;
private static final String MyOnClick1 = "myOnClickTagIcon";


public NotificationPanel(Context parent, RadioOnline radio) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.parent = parent;
    this.radio = radio;
    nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(parent)
            .setContentTitle("Radio")
            .setContentText("Radio Online activada")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setOngoing(true);

    remoteView = new RemoteViews(parent.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);

    if (radio.getPlayer().isPlaying()){
        Toast.makeText(parent, "Se sigue escuchando", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(parent, "No se escucha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //set the button listeners
    setListeners(remoteView);
    nBuilder.setContent(remoteView);

    nManager = (NotificationManager) parent.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(2, nBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (MyOnClick1.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // your onClick action is here
        Toast.makeText(context, "Button1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("Widget", "Clicked button1");
    }
}

public void setListeners(RemoteViews view){
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButtonNbarLogo, getPendingSelfIntent(parent, MyOnClick1));
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action){
    Intent icon = new Intent(context, getClass());
    icon.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, icon, 0);
}

/**
 * Método que cierra el NotificationBar
 */
public void notificationCancel() {
    nManager.cancel(2);
}

}
```

He comprobado que entra en todos los métodos menos en el onReceive. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el onReceive esté a la escucha y recoja el botón que se ha pulsado?.

Sólo necesito recoger que se ha pulsado cada botón del `layout`.

Un saludo y muchas gracias, estoy aprendiendo mucho gracias a ustedes.

Comment: super.onReceive(context, intent); no lo necesitas, pero cual es el problema en realidad? No registra los click?

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys, lo que me pasa es que si yo pulso sobre el 'imageButtonNbarLogo' que tengo declarado, se supone que tiene que mostrarser el 'Toast' en la pantalla pero no aparece. Desde que consiga mostrar el Toast ya podré hacer todo lo que me hace falta para que funcione los botones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he averiguado el problema.
La solución es la siguiente:

En la clase el código quedaría así:

```
public class NotificationPanel extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context parent;
private NotificationManager nManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
private RemoteViews remoteView;
private RadioOnline radio;
private static final String MyOnClick1 = "myOnClickTagIcon";

public NotificationPanel() {
}

public NotificationPanel(Context parent, RadioOnline radio) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.parent = parent;
    this.radio = radio;
    nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(parent)
            .setContentTitle("Radio")
            .setContentText("Radio Online activada")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setOngoing(true);

    remoteView = new RemoteViews(parent.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);


    //set the button listeners
    setListeners(remoteView);
    nBuilder.setContent(remoteView);

    nManager = (NotificationManager) parent.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(2, nBuilder.build());
}

public void setListeners(RemoteViews view){
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButtonNbarLogo, getPendingSelfIntent(parent, MyOnClick1));
}

protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action){
    Intent icon = new Intent(context, getClass());
    icon.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, icon, 0);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //super.onReceive(context, intent);
    Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (MyOnClick1.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // your onClick action is here
        Toast.makeText(context, "Button1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("Widget", "Clicked button1");
    }

}

/**
 * Método que cierra el NotificationBar
 */
public void notificationCancel() {
    nManager.cancel(2);
}

}
```

Luego abría que añadir en el AndroidManifest lo siguiente:

```
<receiver android:name="ecca.radio.clasesRecursos.NotificationPanel" android:enabled="true">
        </receiver>
```

El problema principal era que no tenía declarado el receptor en el AndroidManifest.

Un saludo y muchas gracias, estoy aprendiendo mucho el bonito arte de la programación gracias a ustedes.